# RAM is always written by unknown function,why?

Tags: c, embedded, arm

In my project,I use NXP LPC2368 chip as the embeded system core.The network communication module which I used is RL-ARM lib.Let's have a look :

```
int main(int argc,char**)
{
...
init_TcpNet();
.../*my program to deal with data from network,like callback function.etc*/
while(1)
{
...
main_TcpNet();
...
}
}
```

Unfortunatly,I found a segment in RAM 0x40004730~0x4000476f always being written when I insert the net line,otherwise ,It'll not happen.
Then,I disable `init_TcpNet()`,It didn't happen.On the other hand,when It disable ...(my program),It happened.So,I take a wild guess that the problem is caused by lib function

```
init_TcpNet()
```

At last,I tried to disable `main_TcpNet()` not `init_TcpNet()`.the first output displayd the RAM was written,but after that RAM wasn't written again.
Does any guy encount this problem and can one solve it?
Thanks and regards!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you running out of RAM? I don't think it's so illogical to assume that a networking function needs some memory of its own...

Comment: yes,but,when i disable my functions not lib function,this problem is still here.when i disable lib function init_TcpNet(),it's not here.

Comment: In which section and data is 0x40004730? And if not a linker thingie, is it something chip dependent? When does the data change, and how do you notice it? Might it be a bootloader? Interrupt routine? Some ROM code for network/usb/whatever stack? Bug in some code writing over data it shouldn't?